# Is there code that can force a user to enter a particular format into a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet.

[Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Pqhq5wgLR5NLz_fhvOtKnu3dQ0cMK_j_vKbR736to4/edit?usp=sharing)

When users enter a name into any cell of column A of the sheet named "Unit Standards" I want them to enter that name in a particular format. That is, with the surname first in uppercase then a comma, then the first name in title case then if they are known by a different name that name to be title case in brackets e.g.

- BUSH, George
- TRUMP, Donald
- CLINTON, William (Bill)
- CARTER, James (Jimmy)
- SMITH-JONES, John
- ZETA-JONES, Catherine (Kate)

Is there a way to force them to do that before they leave the cell or the sheet?

Comment: You could probably do it  with a  dialog or webapp which uses client side validation using a regular expression.

Comment: In your situation, is Google Apps Script required to be used?

Comment: Google Apps Script may not be necessary. I would be happy with any method that can achieve the same result.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike Unfortunately it hasn't been resolved

Comment: Thank you for replying. In this case, I would like to respect the posted answer. I think that owner of the answer will resolve your issue by modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a script. Still.

You can have the same results with a simple formula using `Data Validation` on column `A`.

This is the formula to put in cell `A2` for the range `A2:A555`:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2,"^[A-Z]+\b[',']\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\b(\s([A-Z][a-z]+\b))?$")
```

#### Reading the regular expression:

```
^[A-Z]+\b[',']\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\b(\s([A-Z][a-z]+\b))?$
```

- `^[A-Z]+\b`: In the beginning have only 1 or more capital letters until the end of the word
- `[',']\s`: Have a `,` followed by an empty space
- `[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\b`: Have only 1 capital letter and 1 or more small letters till the end of the word
- `(\s\([A-Z][a-z]+\b\))?$`: All of the above **could be** followed `?` by this string.

  - `\s\(`: An empty space and an opening parenthesis `(`
  - `[A-Z][a-z]+\b`: A word starting with just 1 capital followed by 1 or more small letters
  - `\)`: A closing parenthesis
  - `$`: End of string

Comment: Thank you and thank you for the explanation. I added the formula using Data Validation on column A but those with bracketed names e.g. CLINTON, William (Bill) are in violation of the rule.

Comment: I also forgot about hyphenated names e.g. SMITH-JONES, John

Comment: I have copied the link to my spreadsheet. It's the sheet called "Unit Standards"